# Send Outlook email with attachment to list of users in Excel with python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I am able to send email using outlook with below script, but if I try to send attachment it gives error.

File Name_Email.xlsx

```
NAME    EMAIL
Roy     Roy@gmail.com
Jack    Jack@gmail.com
```

Python Script

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd

email_list = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\roy\Name_Email.xlsx')

names = email_list['NAME']
emails = email_list['EMAIL']

for i in range(len(emails)):
   name = names[i]
   email = emails[i]

   outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
   mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
   mail.To = email
   mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
   mail.Body = 'Hello ' + name
   attachment = "hosts.txt"
   mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
   mail.Send()
```

error i am getting:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct.', None, 0, -2147024894), None)
```

The file name is correct, and it's in same directory as the script.

Also I tried to change attachment = 'hosts.txt', but same error. Not sure what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com
import pandas as pd

def mailprepare():
    num = range(0, 5)
    for kk in num:
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
        for accoun in outlook.Session.Accounts:
            if accoun.SmtpAddress == 'your@mail.com':
                newaccount = accoun
                break
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, newaccount))
        data = pd.ExcelFile('D:\\path.xlsx')
        sheet = data.parse('Sheet1')
        name = sheet['Names'][kk]
        mailto = sheet['Mails'][kk]

        att = 'D:\\yourattchment.txt'
        with open(att, 'r') as my_attch:
            myfile=my_attch.read()

        mail.To = mailto
        mail.Subject = 'Subject'
        mail.Body = 'mail body'+ name
        mail.Attachments.Add(att)

        mail.Display(True)
        mail.send

mailprepare()
```

Comment: i have another issue on this, as I want attachment to take a value from for loop. The script works perfectly with static path/file, but doesn't work with variable file from for loop. Please advise as I have posted question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472575/python-win32com-client-to-send-different-attachments-instead-of-fixed-file-path

Answer (score 1):

*You are simply assigning **`hosts.txt`** to a variable but [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Attachments.Add) is looking for full file system path with a file name*

*To get the current directory use*

*Example*

```
import os
print(os.getcwd() + "\hosts.txt")
```

---

*Or*

```
import os

attachment = "hosts.txt"
print(os.path.realpath(attachment))
```

***FYI - I'm on 3.8 python***

Answer (score 0):

your code worked for me when I used:

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')