# win32com.client to send different attachments instead of fixed file path

Tags: python, pandas, email, attachment, win32com

I am able to send email to different recipients on outlook with below script for single attachment, but if I try to send different attachments to each user using for loop, then it fails.

Currently the script is using `attachment = r'C:\Users\roy\Royfile.csv'`. But I want `attachment = file`, so that the attachment changes in each for loop for different users. This part is not working.

Different files for different users, example `Royfile.csv` below. But there are 50 more such files.

```
Folder        FolderOwner    EmailAddress      AttachmentPath
C:\folder1\   Roy            Roy@gmail.com     Royfile.csv
D:\folder2\   Roy            Roy@gmail.com     Royfile.csv
```

2nd file in same folder `Jackfile.csv`:

```
Folder        FolderOwner    EmailAddress      AttachmentPath  
C:\folder3\   Jack            Jack@gmail.com   Jackfile.csv
D:\folder4\   Jack            Jack@gmail.com   Jackfile.csv
```

3rd file for example `Mandyfile.csv`. And same way total 50 files for 50 users in same folder.

```
Folder        FolderOwner    EmailAddress        AttachmentPath
C:\folder5\   Mandy            Mandy@gmail.com   Mandyfile.csv
D:\folder6\   Mandy            Mandy@gmail.com   Mandyfile.csv
```

Python Script

```
import glob, as
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd

for file in glob.glob("*file.csv"):
    print(file)

    email_list = pd.read_csv(file)
    names = email_list['FolderOwner']
    emails = email_list['EmailAddress']
    attachments = email_list['AttachmentPath']

    for i in range(len(emails)):
       print(file)
       name = names[i]
       email = emails[i]
       attachment = r'{}.csv'.format(attachments)
       with open(attachment, 'r') as my_attachment:
          myfile = my_attachment.read()
    
       outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
       mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
       mail.To = email
       mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
       mail.Body = 'Hello ' + name
       mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
       mail.Send()
       break
```

Current output of the script if I remove the attachment part:

```
Royfile.csv
Royfile.csv
Jackfile.csv
Jackfile.csv
Mandyfile.csv
Mandyfile.csv
...
..
.
```

Struggling now with what needs to be for attachment = ???. So that each file gets sent to 50 users.

Comment: How does the file name (and path) of each attachment relate to different users? It's not clear from your question. Also, the nested `for` loop will only iterate once because of the `break` at the end.

Comment: the files are in same path as script, and all file names are starting with user name - Royfile.csv, Jackfile.csv, Mandyfile.csv, etc. I have added break, as the email address is same in each file, but only need to send email once.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really help. Perhaps editing your question and showing how it works for more than a single user would clear things up…

Comment: @martineau, I have added more information in the original question, with more files and current output of script. Hope this helps and I can get a solution. thanks.

Comment: I'm not a pandas expert, but don't understand how, after `email_list = pd.read_csv(file)`, something like `names = email_list['NAME']` and `emails = email_list['EMAIL']` could work since there are no columns named `'NAME'` or `'EMAIL'` in the CSV files being read.

Comment: sorry, I just corrected that in original question.

Comment: If the `file` value is correct in the `print` statement(s), shouldn't the attachment be `attachment = file`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220187/discussion-between-ukki-and-martineau).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer for my question finally, below is full code.
The error was coming, as there was PATH missing.
win32com lib need full path even if the script is running in same folder as the attachments.
works perfectly now. :)

```
import glob, as
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd

for file in glob.glob("*file.csv"):
    print(file)

    email_list = pd.read_csv(file)
    names = email_list['FolderOwner']
    emails = email_list['EmailAddress']
    attachments = email_list['AttachmentPath']
    PATH = "C:\\Users\\roy\\myfolder\\"

    for i in range(len(emails)):
       print("Sending email with " + file)
       name = names[i]
       email = emails[i]
       attachment = attachments[i]
       attachment1 = PATH + attachment 
       with open(attachment1, 'r') as my_attachment:
          myfile = my_attachment.read()
    
       outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
       mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
       mail.To = email
       mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
       mail.Body = 'Hello ' + name
       mail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
       mail.Send()
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your files named how they are distributed in different folders, try to put their all names along with paths in excel sheet in one column and iterate through them the way you are doing for names and mails

```
attachment = r'{}.csv'.format(filepaths from excel sheet)
   with open(attachment, 'r') as my_attachment:
      myfile = my_attachment.read()
```

Comment: I am trying this option now, as I got paths in same csv sheets `Royfile.csv, Jackfile.csv, Mandyfile.csv`, so what all need to be added in `attachment = r'{}.csv'.format(filepaths from excel sheet)` ? as I created a variable `attachments = email_list['AttachmentPath']`. How to call this in attachment similar to name and email?